# How to handle redirect in jest unit test (node.js and express.js)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

Because when I am trying to handle it using
`.expect(301, url)`
then getting error like cannot connect to `localhost:5000/23423432`

```
/**
 * ShortURL to longUrl
 */
// shortUrl  127.0.0.1:57505/1588912666845
test('Should redirect to the longUrl ', async (done) => {
  const param = shortUrl.toString().split('/')[1] ;
  shortUrl = 'http://localhost:5000' + '/' + param ;
  await request(app)
    .get(`${shortUrl}`)
    .expect(301, `${testUrl}`)
  done()
})
```

```
// ERROR
● Should redirect to the longUrl 
    connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:57505
```

and my server is running on port **5000**

Comment: if `shortUrl` has ":57505" then why do you think it would go to port 5000?

Comment: Yes @AlwaysLearning You are right!
I have also tried it on port 5000, still getting same issue!
Please check the code I have updated. Also If you have written some test cases to check redirection then please share with me.